# Read/Write to local without using DirectPipelineRunner in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to read/write data on local without using DirectPipelineRunner?
Suppose I create a dataflow template on cloud and I want it to read some local data. Is this possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You will want to stage your input files to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) first and read from there. Your code will look something like this:

```
p.apply(TextIO.read().from(gs://bucket/folder)
```

where *gs://bucket/folder* is the path to your folder in GCS, and assuming you are using the latest Beam release (2.0.0). Afterwards, you can download the output from GCS to your local computer.

Comment: Yes that I know...so basically you're saying it's not possible the way I want it...okay...thanks @Matthias Baetens

Comment: Not as far as I know. What you could do is use one of the [Google Cloud Storage libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to upload your files, execute your Dataflow template job using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/executing-templates#using-the-rest-api) and then using [Object Change notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) combined with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) to monitor the bucket you are outputting to and download the files from there.